# Given a string, find all number permutations (substrings) while maintaining order and range of value (decode string)

Tags: java, string, algorithm, data-structures, substring

Given a string which is a number, find all substrings that form a number which follows an order and a boundary.

The order is based on the numbers position in the string, and the boundary for a number is 1 and 26 inclusive.

```
Ex 1: String S="24"

Possible: [2,4], [24]

Ex 2: String S="246"

Possible: [2, 4, 6], [24, 6]

Note: the combo [2,46] is NOT considered because 46 is out of range


Ex 3: String S="146"

Possible: [1, 4, 6], [14, 6]

Note: the combo [1,46] is NOT considered because 46 is out of range
```

Each combo is a list of integers, result is A list of a list of integers.

What would be the most efficient approach?

Comment: recursion . . .

Comment: This is the number-to-alphabet problem that has been dealt with here at least twice, and elsewhere quite a bit.  Making no attempt of your own means that you're not yet ready to post a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Length of the string is large enough, you have to solve it in dp technique. 
You can do it with just one state dp like dp[pos]. For each position, you have 2 choice either you take only this digit or you can take next digit if it fits in range.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please try the below code,

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 
    String str = "246"; 
      System.out.println("All substring of abbc are:");
       for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
       for (int j = i+1; j <= str.length(); j++) {
             if((Integer.valueOf(str.substring(i,j)) <26))
                     System.out.println(str.substring(i,j));

       }
      }

}
```